# How to obtain the same numbering of an algorithm for the reference?

Tags: cross-referencing

I don't understand why the reference number in the PDF is wrong.

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
Some text before the algortihm.
\begin{algorithm}   
    \caption {An algorithm.}
    \begin{algorithmic}[H]
        \Function{theAlgorithm}{} : 
        \State test
        \EndFunction\\
        \label{alg:Algo}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
Some more text after the algorithm  \ref{alg:Algo}.
\end{document}
```

PDF:

[image: pdf generated]

I don't know why I get the wrong reference number. How can I obtain the same that is shown in the algorithm title?

Comment: A general comment: It's never a bad idea to place the `\label` instruction *immediately after* the corresponding `\caption` instruction. If you want, you can even place the `\label` instruction *inside* the argument of the `\caption` instruction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error comes from the place where you write the label. You have put it inside the `algorithmic` environment and so it refers to the line within that environment. If you wish to reference the algorithm itself, place `\label` after the `\caption` (and not inside `algorithmic`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[section]{algorithm}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\section{title}
Some text before the algortihm.
\begin{algorithm}   
  \caption{An algorithm.}
  \label{alg:Algo}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Function{theAlgorithm}{} : 
    \State test
    \EndFunction\\
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
Some more text after the algorithm  \ref{alg:Algo}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok I see, but it writes 1 and non 1,1! How can I have the same format?

Comment: @Eric see my edit